# Why don't my forEach loops work with the array of images returned by $('img')?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to save the URLs (src) of multiple images but for some reason, my code isn't getting the job done.

`$('img')` returns an array of images, so logically (or so I'd think) a `forEach` loop should log individual images (or URLs if I add `.attr('src')`). This, however, isn't working. Why?

Here is the relevant part of the code:

```
function fetchURL() {
    let imgURLs = [],
        imgs = $('img');

    imgs.forEach(img => {
        imgURLs.push(img.attr('src'));
    });

    console.log(imgURLs);
}
```

Comment: any errors going on?

Comment: .forEach is jquery? I guess jquery had .each function.

Comment: first step in debugging - **developer** tools console - it will show you why it isn't working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this instead:

```js
    var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
    var imgSrcs = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
        imgSrcs.push(imgs[i].src);
    }

    console.log(imgSrcs);
```

```html
<img src="https://www.nationalgallery.org.uk/server.iip?FIF=/fronts/N-6600-00-000037-WZ-PYR.tif&CNT=1&JTL=1,0">
<img src="https://www.nationalgallery.org.uk/server.iip?FIF=/fronts/N-6600-00-000037-WZ-PYR.tif&CNT=1&JTL=1,0">
<img src="https://www.nationalgallery.org.uk/server.iip?FIF=/fronts/N-6600-00-000037-WZ-PYR.tif&CNT=1&JTL=1,0">
```

Answer (score 1):

`forEach` is a javascript native function, while `$('img')` returns a jQuery object.

If you want to use it, then use `$('img').toArray();` and it will work with forEach.

Secondly change `imgURLs.push(img.attr('src'));` to `imgURLs.push($(img).attr('src'));` as vanilla javascript doesn't have `attr`

```js
function fetchURL() {
    let imgURLs = [],
        imgs = $('img').toArray();

    imgs.forEach(img => {
        imgURLs.push($(img).attr('src'));
    });

    console.log(imgURLs);
}

fetchURL();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="sdfsdf" />
<img src="32442sdf" />
<img src="sdfs343sdfds" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't work with `forEach` before but in jquery you can use `.each()`

```
function fetchURL() {
    var imgURLs = [],
        imgs = $('img');

    imgs.each(function(){   // or $.each(imgs , function(){
        var This_Src = $(this).attr('src');
        imgURLs.push(This_Src);
    });

    console.log(imgURLs);
}
```

Comment: img is what? I think this should be $(this)

Comment: @daremachine I updated the answer while you typing your comment :-)